# Calculator with continuous input in java

Tags: java, calculator

I'm trying to make a calculator where the person can continue to put in numbers like "2+4*7-1" until they press = and then they will get the answer, and I have no idea how to even start. I know how to make a calculator with just 2 numbers but not how to have the user giving new numbers all the time. If anyone have any tips/code I could look at that would help a lot.

Comment: I can tell you how to start. Go to Google.com and enter your question's title and you'll get good starting point

Comment: CLI? GUI? you need to put a starting point :)

Comment: @rivaldragon1, you may look into [ScriptEngine.eval()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#eval(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

Check this  [Creating a Calculator using JFrame](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/321933-creating-a-calculator-using-jframe/) , and this is a step to step tutorial

Answer (score 0):

yes yes i know that i am replying after 2 years but still maybe it will come in handy to other ppl in the future.

its a simple console code no gui.

So here's how i did it on eclipse

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Adv_calc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option;
        double num1, num2, result;
        result = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println("Welcome to The Calculator app");
            System.out.println("Please Choose an option");
            System.out.println("1) Add");
            System.out.println("2) Subtract");
            System.out.println("3) Multiply");
            System.out.println("4) Continue");
            System.out.println("5) Exit");
            System.out.print("Option :: ");
            option = sc.nextInt();
            switch (option) {
            case 1: {
                System.out.println("Addition Calculator");
                System.out.print("Kindly Enter the FIRST Number :: ");
                num1 = sc.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Kindly Enter the SECOND Number :: ");
                num2 = sc.nextDouble();
                result = num1 + num2;
                System.out.print("The Result is :: ");
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                System.out.println("Subtraction Calculator");
                System.out.print("Kindly Enter the FIRST Number :: ");
                num1 = sc.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Kindly Enter the SECOND Number :: ");
                num2 = sc.nextDouble();
                result = num1 - num2;
                System.out.print("The Result is :: ");
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                System.out.println("Multiplication Calculator");
                System.out.print("Kindly Enter the FIRST Number :: ");
                num1 = sc.nextDouble();
                System.out.print("Kindly Enter the SECOND Number :: ");
                num2 = sc.nextDouble();
                result = num1 * num2;
                System.out.print("The Result is :: ");
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
                System.out.println("Please Choose an option");
                System.out.println("1) Add");
                System.out.println("2) Subtract");
                System.out.println("3) Multiply");
                System.out.print("Option :: ");
                option = sc.nextInt();
                switch (option) {
                case 1: {
                    System.out.println("Addition Calculator");
                    System.out.print("Kindly Enter the SECOND Number :: ");
                    num2 = sc.nextDouble();
                    result = result + num2;
                    System.out.print("The Result is :: ");
                    System.out.println(result);
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    System.out.println("Subtraction Calculator");
                    System.out.print("Kindly Enter the SECOND Number :: ");
                    num2 = sc.nextDouble();
                    result = result - num2;
                    System.out.print("The Result is :: ");
                    System.out.println(result);
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    System.out.println("Multiplication Calculator");
                    System.out.print("Kindly Enter the SECOND Number :: ");
                    num2 = sc.nextDouble();
                    result = result * num2;
                    System.out.print("The Result is :: ");
                    System.out.println(result);
                    break;
                }
                }
                break;
            }
            case 5: {
                System.out.println("Thank you for using my program :: ");
                System.out.println("Program will now exit ");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            }
        } while (option != 5);
    }

}
```